# Как в CSS сделать так, чтобы задача, в зависимости от приоретета отправлялась в разные блоки?

Tags: html, css, css3, html5, ruby-on-rails

Есть html файл, который отвечает за создание главного меню сайта.
На сайте отображаются задачи разного приоритета.

```
  <div class="col-md-12">
      <h1>My Tasks</h1>

      <%= link_to "New task", new_task_path, class: 'btn btn-primary' %>

      <% @tasks.each do |task| %>
         <%= render partial: 'task', object: task %>
      <%end %>

      <hr />

      <% @completed_tasks.each do |task| %>
         <%= render partial: 'task', object: task %>
      <% end %>
    </div>
```

Есть CSS файл, в котором задачи разных приоритетов обозначаются разными цветами:

```
    .priority_1 {color: #009090}
    .priority_2 {color: #c09000}
    .priority_3 {color: #c00000}
```

Как сделать так, чтобы задачи разных приоритетов добавлялись в разные блоки на сайте (как бы добавлялись в разные списки)?

Comment: при помощи css это не делается

Comment: Поделить их по приоритетам в контроллере (с помощью скоупа) и отображать каждую группу в своём блоке